# What's the best use case for flatlist in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have tried to get my functions to populate text from url but its not producing any output
I want add text fetch from a url or urls and have it populate in a react native flatlist, this is my attempt at it.

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as React from "react"
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Alert, FlatList, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { color } from "react-native-reanimated";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export function m1() {

  const npop = new Number

  for (i in new Range(0, 999999)) {

    const header = ['https://' + i + '?lang=en-US&region=US&device=desktop']

    fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))

    return (
      <SafeAreaView onLayout={() => m1()}>
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={() => { Sports() }}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={() => { Sports() }}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={() => { Sports() }}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={() => { Sports() }}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={() => { Sports() }}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={() => { Sports() }}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={() => { Sports() }}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={() => { Sports() }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );

  }
}




export class m2 extends React.Component {
  state = { data: [""] }
  componentDidMount() {
    const header = ['https://', 'https://', 'https://']
    return <Text>{fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("span, a").item(response.text))}</Text>
  }

  render() {
    const header = ['https://', 'https://', 'https://']
    return (
      <SafeAreaView onLayout={() => this.componentDidMount()}>
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={style.data}
          data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
          renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}



export class m3 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    snum: new Number,
    data: [""],
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    for (this.state.snum in new Range(this.state.snum, 999999)) {

      const npop = this.state.snum + 1
      const header = ['https://' + npop]
      return fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("span, a").item(response.text))
    }
  }

  render() {
    for (this.state.snum in new Range(this.state.snum, 999999)) {
      const npop = this.state.snum + 1
      const header = ['https://' + npop]
      return (
        <>
          <SafeAreaView onLayout={() => this.componentDidMount()}>
            <FlatList
              style={style.data}
              data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
              renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
            />
            <FlatList
              style={style.data}
              data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
              renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
            />
            <FlatList
              style={style.data}
              data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
              renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
            />
            <FlatList
              style={style.data}
              data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
              renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
            />
            <FlatList
              style={style.data}
              data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
              renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
            />
            <FlatList
              style={style.data}
              data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
              renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
            />
            <FlatList
              style={style.data}
              data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
              renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
            />
            <FlatList
              style={style.data}
              data={fetch(header.find < String > (" ", 0, -1), {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              }).then((response) => document.querySelectorAll("td, a").item(response.text))}
              renderItem={this.componentDidMount()}
            />
          </SafeAreaView >
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default function App() {
  function sendNotification() {
    useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        <>
          <m2 />
          <m3 />
        </>
        m1()
        Alert.alert("Newly Parsed Content ")
      }, 300);
    }, []);
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer onLayout={() => sendNotification()}>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="m1">
        <Drawer.Screen name="m1" component={m1} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="m2" component={m2} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="m3" component={m3} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


const style = StyleSheet.create({
  data: {
    width: "50",
    height: "100%",
    marginBottom: "5%",
    marginTop: "5%",
    marginLeft: "5%",
    marginRight: "5%",
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 50,
    color: '#d5f0ee'
  }
})
```

I tried to incorporate a text view along with the initial code but it still didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

an easier way to do this is to map your renderItems to its own function

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => (<Text >{item}</Text>)
```

then having the flatlist render from there

```
<FlatList data={lists} renderItem={renderItem}/>
```

you would only need one flatlist variable as it will all be appended to the list. I dont know im just a novice as-well but nobody is responding to anyone today it seems... maybe look into sectionlists if thats a better fit